# Protobuf RepeatedField `Get` accessor runtime vs vector `operator[]`

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

In a program where frequent access is required to a certain object(e.g. floating point number) stored in a repeatedfield, how much difference would it make runtime-wise to use a `std::vector` instead of a repeatedfield in terms of accessing the data?

Comment: This benchmark only confirms that the repeated field is allocated sequentially - becuase `std::vector` is. Such benchmarks are hard to judge due to uncertainty in complexities in parallel processing. One important source of uncertainty is the initial cache state. In order to do a good bench mark, cache must be set to similar state prior to each test - possibly through a proper fence. More over the difference in the compared methods generally stem from difference in initialization/finalization routines - due to similarity in underlying data structures. But since the rest of your code relies on

Comment: Protocole buffers, the vector approach might need some glue code and not-so-clean patches.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the insight! How would you suggest setting up the cache to a similar state?

Comment: Hi, It is generally hardware platform dependent. But a memory fence is needed; A low level API to sync/flush the cache. But I still doubt that such a test would result in reliable results, unless of course tested on a hard realtime platform.

Comment: Right now we are speaking in a strictly single-threaded question.

Comment: Is the OS single threaded? Hardware is still piplined nevertheless. So an atomic operation with minimum guarantees is the least we need. What's preventing interrupts from happening?

Answer (score 0):

I created a program to test! Improvements welcome. Basically there isn't much difference:
1.68% of runtime in a simple example program.

my_stuff.proto:

```proto
syntax = "proto3";

message My_stuff{
  repeated double to_my_floats = 1;
}
```

scrap.cpp:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include "my_stuff.pb.h"

using std::vector;

const int arr_size = 500;
vector<double> my_vec = vector<double>(arr_size, 0);
My_stuff* ptr;

void read_vector(){
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i)
        std::cout << "\r vec:" << my_vec[rand()%arr_size];
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

void read_field(){
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i)
        std::cout << "\r field:" << ptr->to_my_floats(rand()%arr_size);
    std::cout << std::endl;
}


int main(){
    google::protobuf::Arena arena;
    
    std::cout << "Initializing!" <<std::endl;
    ptr = google::protobuf::Arena::CreateMessage<My_stuff>(&arena);
    for(int i = 0; i < arr_size; ++i){
        my_vec[i] = static_cast<double>(rand()%999);
        ptr->add_to_my_floats(static_cast<double>(rand()%999));
    }
    std::cout << "Testing!" << std::endl;
    read_vector();
    read_field();
    std::cout << "Done!" <<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

There isn't much of a diference according callgrind ( By percentage of runtime ):
[image]

Slight differences in Cache misses though, which might be consequential.

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Ir                     I1mr               ILmr           Dr                   D1mr            DLmr           Dw                   D1mw           DLmw            file:function
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
27,000,018 ( 0.45%)    2 ( 0.00%)         2 ( 0.04%)     3,000,006 ( 0.19%)   0               0              4,000,005 ( 0.40%)   0              0               scrap.cpp:read_field()
28,000,016 ( 0.47%)    4 ( 0.00%)         2 ( 0.04%)     3,000,005 ( 0.19%)   26 ( 0.04%)     0              4,000,004 ( 0.40%)   0              0               scrap.cpp:read_vector()
```